# How to plot a scatter graph in Wolfram Alpha?

Tags: wolfram-alpha, graph

Is it possible to plot a simple scatter graph of points without any joining lines or lines of best fit?

I have tried to use `ListPlot` but it just interprets that as `plot` which causes the points to be joined with lines.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ListPlot` option `Joined->False`

Comment: I'm using wolfram alpha, I can't see where to use this.